# how to traverse and filter an array?

Tags: php, arrays

how to traverse the array and filter all except the current month?

> example:

i have this:

```
    array(1) {
  [257]=>
  array(10) {
    ["recaudacion"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "2017-01-07"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "2017-02-07"
      [2]=>
      string(10) "2017-03-07"
      [3]=>
      string(10) "2017-04-07"
      [4]=>
      string(10) "2017-05-07"
      [5]=>
      string(10) "2017-06-07"
      [6]=>
      string(10) "2017-07-07"
      [7]=>
      string(10) "2017-08-07"
      [8]=>
      string(10) "2017-09-07"
      [9]=>
      string(10) "2017-10-07"
      [10]=>
      string(10) "2017-11-07"
      [11]=>
      string(10) "2017-12-07"
      [12]=>
      string(10) "2018-01-07"
    }
    ["Contribuyentes Convenio Multilateral"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "2017-01-13"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "2017-02-13"
      [2]=>
      string(10) "2017-03-13"
      [3]=>
      string(10) "2017-04-17"
      [4]=>
      string(10) "2017-05-15"
      [5]=>
      string(10) "2017-06-13"
      [6]=>
      string(10) "2017-07-13"
      [7]=>
      string(10) "2017-08-14"
      [8]=>
      string(10) "2017-09-13"
      [9]=>
      string(10) "2017-10-13"
      [10]=>
      string(10) "2017-11-13"
      [11]=>
      string(10) "2017-12-13"
      [12]=>
      string(10) "2018-01-13"
    }
    ["Contribuyentes Locales,Activid. Especiales y Salas de Recreacion"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "2017-01-16"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "2017-02-15"
      [2]=>
      string(10) "2017-03-15"
      [3]=>
      string(10) "2017-04-17"
      [4]=>
      string(10) "2017-05-15"
      [5]=>
      string(10) "2017-06-15"
      [6]=>
      string(10) "2017-07-17"
      [7]=>
      string(10) "2017-08-16"
      [8]=>
      string(10) "2017-09-15"
      [9]=>
      string(10) "2017-10-16"
      [10]=>
      string(10) "2017-11-15"
      [11]=>
      string(10) "2017-12-15"
      [12]=>
      string(10) "2018-01-16"
    }
    ["Regimen simplificado"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "2017-01-20"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "2017-02-00"
      [2]=>
      string(10) "2017-03-20"
      [3]=>
      string(10) "2017-04-00"
      [4]=>
      string(10) "2017-05-22"
      [5]=>
      string(10) "2017-06-00"
      [6]=>
      string(10) "2017-07-20"
      [7]=>
      string(10) "2017-08-00"
      [8]=>
      string(10) "2017-09-20"
      [9]=>
      string(10) "2017-10-00"
      [10]=>
      string(10) "2017-11-20"
      [11]=>
      string(10) "2017-12-00"
      [12]=>
      string(10) "2018-01-20"
    }
    ["Declaracion Jurada Fiscal 2016 Contibuyentes Locales"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "2017-01-00"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "2017-02-00"
      [2]=>
      string(10) "2017-03-00"
      [3]=>
      string(10) "2017-04-00"
      [4]=>
      string(10) "2017-05-00"
      [5]=>
      string(10) "2017-06-00"
      [6]=>
      string(10) "2017-07-00"
      [7]=>
      string(10) "2017-08-00"
      [8]=>
      string(10) "2017-09-00"
      [9]=>
      string(10) "2017-10-00"
      [10]=>
      string(10) "2017-11-00"
      [11]=>
      string(10) "2017-12-00"
      [12]=>
      string(10) "2018-01-00"
    }
    ["Recategorizacion cuatrimestral regimen simplificado"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(11) "2017-01-131"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "2017-02-00"
      [2]=>
      string(10) "2017-03-00"
      [3]=>
      string(10) "2017-04-00"
      [4]=>
      string(11) "2017-05-131"
      [5]=>
      string(10) "2017-06-00"
      [6]=>
      string(10) "2017-07-00"
      [7]=>
      string(10) "2017-08-00"
      [8]=>
      string(11) "2017-09-130"
      [9]=>
      string(10) "2017-10-00"
      [10]=>
      string(10) "2017-11-00"
      [11]=>
      string(10) "2017-12-00"
      [12]=>
      string(11) "2018-01-131"
    }
    ["Declaracion Jurada anual 2016 Contribuyentes de convenio multilateral"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "2017-01-00"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "2017-02-00"
      [2]=>
      string(10) "2017-03-00"
      [3]=>
      string(10) "2017-04-00"
      [4]=>
      string(10) "2017-05-00"
      [5]=>
      string(10) "2017-06-30"
      [6]=>
      string(10) "2017-07-00"
      [7]=>
      string(10) "2017-08-00"
      [8]=>
      string(10) "2017-09-00"
      [9]=>
      string(10) "2017-10-00"
      [10]=>
      string(10) "2017-11-00"
      [11]=>
      string(10) "2017-12-00"
      [12]=>
      string(10) "2018-01-00"
    }
    ["Impuestos de Sellos"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "2017-01-10"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "2017-02-10"
      [2]=>
      string(10) "2017-03-10"
      [3]=>
      string(10) "2017-04-10"
      [4]=>
      string(10) "2017-05-10"
      [5]=>
      string(10) "2017-06-10"
      [6]=>
      string(10) "2017-07-10"
      [7]=>
      string(10) "2017-08-10"
      [8]=>
      string(10) "2017-09-10"
      [9]=>
      string(10) "2017-10-10"
      [10]=>
      string(10) "2017-11-10"
      [11]=>
      string(10) "2017-12-10"
      [12]=>
      string(10) "2018-01-10"
    }
    ["Ingresos Brutos Contribuyentes Locales"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "21/02/2017"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "21/03/2017"
      [2]=>
      string(10) "19/04/2017"
      [3]=>
      string(10) "19/05/2017"
      [4]=>
      string(10) "21/06/2017"
      [5]=>
      string(10) "19/07/2017"
      [6]=>
      string(10) "22/08/2017"
      [7]=>
      string(10) "19/09/2017"
      [8]=>
      string(10) "19/10/2017"
      [9]=>
      string(10) "21/11/2017"
      [10]=>
      string(10) "19/12/2017"
      [11]=>
      string(10) "19/01/2018"
      [12]=>
      string(10) "04/04/2017"
    }
    ["Ingresos Brutos de Convenio Multilateral"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "13/02/2017"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "13/03/2017"
      [2]=>
      string(10) "17/04/2017"
      [3]=>
      string(10) "15/05/2017"
      [4]=>
      string(10) "13/06/2017"
      [5]=>
      string(10) "13/07/2017"
      [6]=>
      string(10) "14/08/2017"
      [7]=>
      string(10) "13/09/2017"
      [8]=>
      string(10) "13/10/2017"
      [9]=>
      string(10) "13/11/2017"
      [10]=>
      string(10) "13/12/2017"
      [11]=>
      string(10) "15/01/2018"
      [12]=>
      string(10) "30/06/2017"
    }
  }
}
array(1) {
  [258]=>
  array(10) {
    ["recaudacion"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "2017-01-07"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "2017-02-07"
      [2]=>
      string(10) "2017-03-07"
      [3]=>
      string(10) "2017-04-07"
      [4]=>
      string(10) "2017-05-07"
      [5]=>
      string(10) "2017-06-07"
      [6]=>
      string(10) "2017-07-07"
      [7]=>
      string(10) "2017-08-07"
      [8]=>
      string(10) "2017-09-07"
      [9]=>
      string(10) "2017-10-07"
      [10]=>
      string(10) "2017-11-07"
      [11]=>
      string(10) "2017-12-07"
      [12]=>
      string(10) "2018-01-07"
    }
    ["Contribuyentes Convenio Multilateral"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "2017-01-13"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "2017-02-13"
      [2]=>
      string(10) "2017-03-13"
      [3]=>
      string(10) "2017-04-17"
      [4]=>
      string(10) "2017-05-15"
      [5]=>
      string(10) "2017-06-13"
      [6]=>
      string(10) "2017-07-13"
      [7]=>
      string(10) "2017-08-14"
      [8]=>
      string(10) "2017-09-13"
      [9]=>
      string(10) "2017-10-13"
      [10]=>
      string(10) "2017-11-13"
      [11]=>
      string(10) "2017-12-13"
      [12]=>
      string(10) "2018-01-13"
    }
    ["Contribuyentes Locales,Activid. Especiales y Salas de Recreacion"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "2017-01-17"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "2017-02-16"
      [2]=>
      string(10) "2017-03-16"
      [3]=>
      string(10) "2017-04-18"
      [4]=>
      string(10) "2017-05-16"
      [5]=>
      string(10) "2017-06-16"
      [6]=>
      string(10) "2017-07-18"
      [7]=>
      string(10) "2017-08-17"
      [8]=>
      string(10) "2017-09-18"
      [9]=>
      string(10) "2017-10-17"
      [10]=>
      string(10) "2017-11-16"
      [11]=>
      string(10) "2017-12-18"
      [12]=>
      string(10) "2018-01-17"
    }
    ["Regimen simplificado"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "2017-01-23"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "2017-02-00"
      [2]=>
      string(10) "2017-03-21"
      [3]=>
      string(10) "2017-04-00"
      [4]=>
      string(10) "2017-05-23"
      [5]=>
      string(10) "2017-06-00"
      [6]=>
      string(10) "2017-07-21"
      [7]=>
      string(10) "2017-08-00"
      [8]=>
      string(10) "2017-09-21"
      [9]=>
      string(10) "2017-10-00"
      [10]=>
      string(10) "2017-11-21"
      [11]=>
      string(10) "2017-12-00"
      [12]=>
      string(10) "2018-01-23"
    }
    ["Declaracion Jurada Fiscal 2016 Contibuyentes Locales"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "2017-01-00"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "2017-02-00"
      [2]=>
      string(10) "2017-03-00"
      [3]=>
      string(10) "2017-04-00"
      [4]=>
      string(10) "2017-05-00"
      [5]=>
      string(10) "2017-06-00"
      [6]=>
      string(10) "2017-07-00"
      [7]=>
      string(10) "2017-08-00"
      [8]=>
      string(10) "2017-09-00"
      [9]=>
      string(10) "2017-10-00"
      [10]=>
      string(10) "2017-11-00"
      [11]=>
      string(10) "2017-12-00"
      [12]=>
      string(10) "2018-01-00"
    }
    ["Recategorizacion cuatrimestral regimen simplificado"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(11) "2017-01-131"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "2017-02-00"
      [2]=>
      string(10) "2017-03-00"
      [3]=>
      string(10) "2017-04-00"
      [4]=>
      string(11) "2017-05-131"
      [5]=>
      string(10) "2017-06-00"
      [6]=>
      string(10) "2017-07-00"
      [7]=>
      string(10) "2017-08-00"
      [8]=>
      string(11) "2017-09-130"
      [9]=>
      string(10) "2017-10-00"
      [10]=>
      string(10) "2017-11-00"
      [11]=>
      string(10) "2017-12-00"
      [12]=>
      string(11) "2018-01-131"
    }
    ["Declaracion Jurada anual 2016 Contribuyentes de convenio multilateral"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "2017-01-00"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "2017-02-00"
      [2]=>
      string(10) "2017-03-00"
      [3]=>
      string(10) "2017-04-00"
      [4]=>
      string(10) "2017-05-00"
      [5]=>
      string(10) "2017-06-30"
      [6]=>
      string(10) "2017-07-00"
      [7]=>
      string(10) "2017-08-00"
      [8]=>
      string(10) "2017-09-00"
      [9]=>
      string(10) "2017-10-00"
      [10]=>
      string(10) "2017-11-00"
      [11]=>
      string(10) "2017-12-00"
      [12]=>
      string(10) "2018-01-00"
    }
    ["Impuestos de Sellos"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "2017-01-10"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "2017-02-10"
      [2]=>
      string(10) "2017-03-10"
      [3]=>
      string(10) "2017-04-10"
      [4]=>
      string(10) "2017-05-10"
      [5]=>
      string(10) "2017-06-10"
      [6]=>
      string(10) "2017-07-10"
      [7]=>
      string(10) "2017-08-10"
      [8]=>
      string(10) "2017-09-10"
      [9]=>
      string(10) "2017-10-10"
      [10]=>
      string(10) "2017-11-10"
      [11]=>
      string(10) "2017-12-10"
      [12]=>
      string(10) "2018-01-10"
    }
    ["Ingresos Brutos Contribuyentes Locales"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "22/02/2017"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "22/03/2017"
      [2]=>
      string(10) "20/04/2017"
      [3]=>
      string(10) "22/05/2017"
      [4]=>
      string(10) "22/06/2017"
      [5]=>
      string(10) "20/07/2017"
      [6]=>
      string(10) "23/08/2017"
      [7]=>
      string(10) "20/09/2017"
      [8]=>
      string(10) "20/10/2017"
      [9]=>
      string(10) "22/11/2017"
      [10]=>
      string(10) "20/12/2017"
      [11]=>
      string(10) "22/01/2018"
      [12]=>
      string(10) "05/04/2017"
    }
    ["Ingresos Brutos de Convenio Multilateral"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "13/02/2017"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "13/03/2017"
      [2]=>
      string(10) "17/04/2017"
      [3]=>
      string(10) "15/05/2017"
      [4]=>
      string(10) "13/06/2017"
      [5]=>
      string(10) "13/07/2017"
      [6]=>
      string(10) "14/08/2017"
      [7]=>
      string(10) "13/09/2017"
      [8]=>
      string(10) "13/10/2017"
      [9]=>
      string(10) "13/11/2017"
      [10]=>
      string(10) "13/12/2017"
      [11]=>
      string(10) "15/01/2018"
      [12]=>
      string(10) "30/06/2017"
    }
  }
}
```

and i want this:

```
array(1) {
  [257]=>
  array(10) {
    ["recaudacion"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "2017-10-07"
    }
    ["Contribuyentes Convenio Multilateral"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "2017-10-13"
    }
    ["Contribuyentes Locales,Activid. Especiales y Salas de Recreacion"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "2017-10-16"
    }
    ["Regimen simplificado"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "2017-10-00"
    }
    ["Declaracion Jurada Fiscal 2016 Contibuyentes Locales"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "2017-10-00"
    }
    ["Recategorizacion cuatrimestral regimen simplificado"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "2017-10-00"
    }
    ["Declaracion Jurada anual 2016 Contribuyentes de convenio multilateral"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "2017-10-00"
    }
    ["Impuestos de Sellos"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "2017-10-10"
    }
    ["Ingresos Brutos Contribuyentes Locales"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "19/10/2017"
    }
    ["Ingresos Brutos de Convenio Multilateral"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "13/10/2017"
    }
  }
}
array(1) {
  [258]=>
  array(10) {
    ["recaudacion"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "2017-10-07"
    }
    ["Contribuyentes Convenio Multilateral"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "2017-10-13"
    }
    ["Contribuyentes Locales,Activid. Especiales y Salas de Recreacion"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "2017-10-17"
    }
    ["Regimen simplificado"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "2017-10-00"
    }
    ["Declaracion Jurada Fiscal 2016 Contibuyentes Locales"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "2017-10-00"
    }
    ["Recategorizacion cuatrimestral regimen simplificado"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "2017-10-00"
    }
    ["Declaracion Jurada anual 2016 Contribuyentes de convenio multilateral"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "2017-10-00"
    }
    ["Impuestos de Sellos"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "2017-10-10"
    }
    ["Ingresos Brutos Contribuyentes Locales"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "20/10/2017"
    }
    ["Ingresos Brutos de Convenio Multilateral"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "13/10/2017"
    }
  }
}
```

I do not care about the day but it must be kept.

my code here:

```
function filtrarVencimientos($arrayCompleto){

    $filtered = array_filter($arrayCompleto, 'month');

var_dump($filtered);
    return $filtered;
}

function month($outer) {
  $dt = new \DateTime;
$current_month = $dt->format('Y-m');

foreach ($outer as &$middle) {
    foreach ($middle as &$inner) {
        foreach ($inner as &$item) {
            if (date_format($item, 'Y-m') == $current_month) {
              unset($item);
            }
            return $item;
        }


    }


  }

}

function getFiltrado(){
  $arrayCompleto = getVencimientosPorPerfil();

  $arrayFiltrado = filtrarVencimientos($arrayCompleto);

  return $arrayFiltrado;
}
```

> I tried using stripos but it does not support arrays and I could not think of a way to do it ... any ideas?
>
> I edited the question by adding my code and the complete result of the original array

Comment: foreach loop, then you can use strpos, or anything else

Comment: i tried this but returns an empty array: `function month($var) {
  $response = false;

  if (is_array($var)) {

    foreach ($var as $item){
    $response = month($item);
  }

  } else {
    $date = date('Y-m');
    $response = (stripos($var, $date) !== false);
  }

  return $response;
}`

Comment: your array is multidimensional - your code dose not take that in to account

Comment: so how can i do that? sorry, im not the best in arrays...

Comment: see below for one option.

Comment: Can you provide the original data structure / example so we can see how this all works?

Comment: @giollianosulit i edited, Is that what you asked for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop up to dates, compare to current date, unset if false

```
foreach($array as $key1 => $outer) {
    foreach($outer as $key2 => $inner) {
        foreach ($inner as $key3 => $date) {
            // Added substr function to replace 00 Days to 01
            if (substr($date, 8, 2) === '00') {
                $date = str_replace('00', '01', $date);
            } // End of Edit
            $date = strtotime($date);
            if (date('m', $date) !== date('m')) {
                unset($array[$key1][$key2][$key3]);
            }
            // Added new if condition to remove empty inner arrays
            if (count($array[$key1][$key2]) === 0 ) {
                unset($array[$key1][$key2]);
            } // End of Edit
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: very close! but it returns a few array badly:   

``` ["Contribuyentes Locales,Activid. Especiales y Salas de Recreacion"]=>
    array(1) {
      [9]=>
      string(10) "2017-10-17"
    }
    ["Regimen simplificado"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["Declaracion Jurada Fiscal 2016 Contibuyentes Locales"]=>
    array(1) {
      [10]=>
      string(10) "2017-11-00"
    }```

Comment: Sorry just saw the edited examples. Is 2017-11-00 on your data considered a date?

Comment: I do not understand the question, however I need that to return 2017-10-00

Comment: As I said, only some arrays gave me a wrong date or empty

Comment: ["Regimen simplificado"]=>
    array(0) {
    } ["Declaracion Jurada Fiscal 2016 Contibuyentes Locales"]=>
    array(1) {
      [10]=>
      string(10) "2017-11-00"
    }
    ["Recategorizacion cuatrimestral regimen simplificado"]=>
    array(1) {
      [10]=>
      string(10) "2017-11-00"
    }
    ["Declaracion Jurada anual 2016 Contribuyentes de convenio multilateral"]=>
    array(1) {
      [10]=>
      string(10) "2017-11-00"
    }["Ingresos Brutos Contribuyentes Locales"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["Ingresos Brutos de Convenio Multilateral"]=>
    array(0) {
    }

Comment: Please check edited answer. I make those dates with 00 to 01 to count them to next month. Also I added a condition to remove empty arrays in case all dates are not current month

Comment: MAN, I LOVE YOU! <3 JAJAJAJAJA

Comment: Hahaha. The dates with '00' _e.g. 2017-11-00_ still bothers me though. Please try not to use those. Anyways. Goodluck

Answer (score 1):

It would be nested [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loops with a check for current month, something like this:

```
$dt = new \DateTime;
$current_month = $dt->format('Ym');

foreach ($outer as &$middle) {
    foreach ($middle as &$inner) {
        foreach ($inner as &$item) {
            if (date_format($item, 'Ym') == $current_month) {
                unset($item)
            }
        }

        unset($item); // 5.6 compat
    }

    unset($middle); // 5.6 compat
}

unset($inner); // 5.6 compat
```

If using [PHP 7.0 or greater](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.foreach), you can remove the `5.6 compat` `unset` calls.

Comment: might want a recursive loop, in case its more than 2d

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` in ther  `foreach ($inner as &$item)`

Comment: Yeah, that's example code because you posted the `var_dump` of your arrays, not your code, so I can't be more specific.  You'll have to modify the code to work with whatever your variables are.  @nogad I wrote this specifically for his output.  If he wants something more dynamic he'll have to handle that on his own.